# Single function to retrive data from Broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android

I have a function ReadConfig in non activity class which is invoked by a Service. This function uses IntentService to read data from a file.

**Function in non activity class**

```
//Start of globalVariables
public static boolean received;
public static String actionID = "ACTION_ID";
public static ArrayList<String> configData;
public static BroadcastReceiver configDataReceiver;
//End of globalVariables

public static List<String> ReadConfig(Context context, String configFileName)
{
    configDataReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent)
        {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(actionID))
            {
                configData = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("CONFIGDATA");
                received = true;
            }
        }
    };
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
            .registerReceiver(configDataReceiver,new IntentFilter(actionID));
    Intent workRequest = new Intent(context,IOConfigurations.class);
    workRequest.putExtra("OPERATION","READ");
    workRequest.putExtra("FILENAME",configFileName);
    //Calling intentservice
    context.startService(workRequest);

    //Wait for broadcast receiver to get data and assign to global variables
    while (!received)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(configDataReceiver);
    return configData;
}
```

**Intent Service**

```
    Intent configData = new Intent(actionID);
    configData.putStringArrayListExtra("CONFIGDATA",FileOperations.readFile(fileName));
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(configData);
```

The intent service is getting invoked and broadcasts the data but the receiver however doesn't receive any data from Broadcast manager and the while loop continues for ever.

Answer (score 0):

check my comments

```
    public static List<String> ReadConfig(Context context, String configFileName)
{
    configDataReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent)
        {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(actionID))
            {
                configData = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("CONFIGDATA");
                received = true;
            }
        }
    };
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
            .registerReceiver(configDataReceiver,new IntentFilter(actionID));
    Intent workRequest = new Intent(context,IOConfigurations.class);
    workRequest.putExtra("OPERATION","READ");
    workRequest.putExtra("FILENAME",configFileName);
    //Calling intentservice
    context.startService(workRequest);

    //Wait for broadcast receiver to get data and assign to global variables
    while (!received)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

   // Why here your unregistering the broacast listener, 
// Your registering and unregistering in same call, unregiter when your work is done        

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(configDataReceiver);
    return configData;
}
```

Comment: When the while loop is complete then the work is done, so I'm unregistering the listener after the while loop is done.

Comment: ACTION_ID value change to some like this = > com.example.data_fetch_action

Comment: you are right, I used intent.getAction() method in Intenet service which returned null and not "ACTION_ID", The code works fine now from Service, however the same is not working when called from the activity, the activity just freezes forever.

Comment: i think bouded service is waht require.